Was the singularity a boson?
I was wondering if there is any truth in the perspective that the singularity point at the beginning of our universe would be considered a boson.
I have heard it said that the universe at that one instant was essentially as much a "particle" as any other fundamental particle of the standard model.
If that were true, it makes me ask the question, "What kind of particle was it?" and since characteristics like charge and mass and spin were meaningless at that point in the evolution of the universe, that means it would have a spin equal to zero, making it a scalar boson, like the Higgs.
Is there any validity to a perspective like this?

I have heard it said that the universe at that one instant was essentially as much a "particle" as any other fundamental particle of the standard model. I’ve never heard this said. Do you remember who you heard it from?

Note that the Big Bang did not happen at a point so your question is not meaningful.

No. Within our best theories, this is incorrect.
In general relativity, a singularity is a hole in spacetime (which is properly defined by means of geodesic incompleteness). It is not a particle and it does not behave like a particle. I can't see any way in which a singularity would resemble a particle in the sense of particle physics. The singularity is a way for us to understand that the spacetime is punctured. It does not live on the spacetime, and it is not an excitation of any field.
Caveat: the standard model and general relativity break down near singularities, because you can't make the assumptions we use to work with them. I am answering from the perspective of quantum field theory in curved spacetime, but this theory is expected to break down before one gets to the singularity. Nevertheless, it is the best possible option to answer this question, since no reliable current theory describes what happens near singularities (and most attempts at quantum gravity simply remove the singularity completely).

I think it is beginning to make a little more sense to me. However, it has also dredged up more questions. The image of a singularity being a way for us to understand that spacetime is being punctured. That is a helpful mnemonic image for me. Because it is like it is a zero-dimensional puncture into our universe, but with all the pressure behind it of the entirety of the energy that would become our multi-dimensional universe. So in the first Planck unit of time in our universe, gravity was the first of those pressures to come through... to separate from the other pressures that would follow.

Bringing with it, our first dimension. And the other forces bringing in the rest of the dimensions of our universe. This is really cool. Thanks for your answer.

I don't think you should take "punctured" literally.  Space or spacetime is not a sheet of material despite the common analogy, and there is no space "outside" to form a hole.  It's just a metaphorical way of saying there is a singular point in the mathematics, exactly like $x=0$ in $f(x)=1/x$, or $x=\pi/2$ in $f(x)=\tan(x)$

@RC_23 In general relativity, you take punctured literally. Your examples concern a function exploding on a background spacetime. In GR, spacetime itself is "exploding". Since this makes no sense, the point simply doesn't exist. Any advanced GR textbook will have a hard time describing singularities exactly because they are not points in spacetime. You have to talk about geodesic incompleteness precisely because of this

We may have a difference of opinion on the accuracy of the term "punctured" for describing the singular spacetime.  But the important thing is that most physicists agree the equations of GR do not accurately describe the region near the center of a BH.  So it doesn't really matter what it would "look like" if they did. The theory prediction is invalid.

It also brings up a more basic question of how well any theory of pure math can describe a real system. Spherical cows in a vacuum.  E.g. the theory of elastic vibration describes a vibrating bracket, until it hits a resonance point and, rather than the oscillations growing to infinity as the math says, it just breaks because the material strength was exceeded.
